# Eventhandler won't let me select graphic when MouseClicked is assigned

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to digitize points in an image and I would like to use KeyDown events to clear selected points.
For the KeyDown to work the image must be selected by clicking it (orange border shows around the image).
When the MouseClicked is assigned it will register the point in my image, but the image won't be selected, and so the KeyDown won't work.
I've figured out that I can select the image using the right mouse button instead.
I was hoping to find a way to have the code automatically select the image for me as soon as the document is created.
Does anybody know how to do this?

This is for my research so that I can digitize the location of features within an ultrasound image.

I've tried using the SelectionMove[] function in a couple of different ways, but it doesn't work.

```
CreateDocument[
  DynamicModule[
   {pnts = {}},
   EventHandler[
    Show[
     img,
     Epilog -> {Red, Point[Dynamic[pnts]]}
     ],
    {
     {"MouseClicked", 
       1} :> {AppendTo[pnts, MousePosition["Graphics"]]},
     "EscapeKeyDown" :> {pnts = {}}
     }
    ]
   ]
  ];
```

It opens the image, and I can place points. However, I can't clear them with the EscapeKeyDown.

my image -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKKqC.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is vaguely answered in the docs: "For mouse events, EventHandler[*expr*, ...] handles events for which the mouse is within the rectangular region defined by the display of expr."  Implying that keyboard events work differently.

You could use something like this.

```
pnts = {};
SetOptions[CreateDocument[
   EventHandler[Show[img, Epilog -> {Red, Point[Dynamic[pnts]]}],
    {"MouseClicked", 1} :> AppendTo[pnts, MousePosition["Graphics"]]]], 
 NotebookEventActions :> {"EscapeKeyDown" :> (pnts = {})}]
```